# How to get the $.data() on the option inside the dropdown?

Tags: jquery, jquery-data

```
$('#selectSurvey').append('<option value="1" data-img="/path/image.png">'+ Option1 +'</option>');

$('#selectSurvey').on('change',function(e){
    $('#image-here').attr('src',this.data('img')); //wrong
});
```

How do I get the data in *Option1* inside the dropdown on change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to grab the selected `option` from the select element then retrieve the data,

```
$('#selectSurvey').on('change',function(e){
  $('#image-here').attr('src',$(this).find('option:selected').data('img')); 
});
```

Since the `data-img` has been set with the `option` element not with the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
$('#selectSurvey').on('change',function(e){
   var img = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-img');
   $('#image-here').attr('src',img); 
});
```

or use .data() (if your jQuery version is newer ie >= 1.4.3)

```
$('#selectSurvey').on('change',function(e){
   var img = $(this).find('option:selected').data('img');
   $('#image-here').attr('src',img); 
});
```

Comment: You answered for the question after 8 minutes. Make it answer quickly